# SwiftのAVPlayerでFailedになる理由

Tags: swift, ios

SwiftのAVPlayerでネットワークからの動画再生を試しています。mp4ファイルをストリーミング再生を試みています。

PlayerのStatusを監視するためにKVOをセットします。

```
self.playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .New | .Initial, context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String,
  ofObject object: AnyObject,
  change: [NSObject : AnyObject],
  context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {}
```

でステータス変化時にこのfunctionで受けます。

statusが.ReadyToPlayのときには、play()で再生できますが、.Failedになるときがあります。

しかし、同じファイルを再生していますが、.ReadyToPlayになるときもあれば、.Failedになるときもあります。

はっきりしていませんが、ネットワークのスピードは早く出ているのですが、サーバのハードディスクが動きだした最初のアクセスが.Failedになるような気がします。(何度かやっていてそのような気がしてます)

どのようなときが.Failedになるのでしょうか？また.Failedになってもplay()すると再生ができる可能性はあるのでしょうか？

ご存知であればご教示お願いします。

Comment: ネットワークでの通信は様々な理由でエラーになるので、一口に「どのようなときが.Failedになるのでしょうか？」と聞かれても難しいです。Appleのドキュメントにも網羅してリストアップされているわけではありません。`AVPlayerItem`には`error`と言うプロパティがあるので、`.Failed`となった場合にはその内容を出力してみると何かの情報がわかるかもしれません。`print(self.playerItem.error)`とか言う感じです。なお、ご質問中のコード部分はコードとしての整形(編集領域内でコード全体を選択して`{}`アイコンをクリックするだけです)を行うようにお願いします。

Comment: print(playerItem.error?.localizedDescription)  
でエラー内容を表示させてみました。  
2017-08-14 18:38:17.370292+0900 xxxxx[10299:3248129] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.  
Optional("操作を完了できませんでした")  
というエラーが発生してますが、これはどういった意味でしょうか？ネットワーク帯域が足りないとか？

Comment: 残念ながらエラーメッセージだけでは有用な情報が得られていないようですね。そのメッセージは特にメッセージが定義されていないエラー全般に割り振られているものです。`print(playerItem.error)`だけではどうなりますか? (デバッグ用と割り切って警告等は無視してください。)

Comment: Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "操作を完了できませんでした" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=原因不明のエラーが起きました（-12245）, NSLocalizedDescription=操作を完了できませんでした, NSURL=http://aaa.com/contents/testcontents.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x17425ff20 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12245 "(null)"}})  との表示がされます。※URLは一部修正。

Comment: エラー情報ありがとうございました。できればその情報はご質問本文に追記しておいてください。で、Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12245で調べてみました。[古いAppleのDev Forumsの記事](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1131865#1131865)(閲覧には開発者アカウントが必要)ではAppleの技術者が「極めて内部的なエラーコード。内部のRPC機構に関連」、[英語版StackOverflowの記事](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23134865/6541007)…元の書き方が非同期通信通信を利用している場合(ObjCですが)、この書き方で動くんじゃないかという提案あり。他、リモートからのAVAssetの読み込みで同じエラーが出たという記事あり。と言うところで、残念ながら「原因」「play()すると再生ができる」等について答えられる情報はありません。